# iOS Firebase Database URL

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have been searching the web and gone through all tutorials I found about this subject, read the API reference but ultimately couldn't find any solution to my simple requirement.

In iOS / Swift, one has to install a "GoogleService-Info.plist" in the xCode project and then call `FIRApp.configure()` in the AppDelegate in order to load the configuration from the aforementioned plist file.

That all works perfectly, but what I would like now is being able to retrieve the parameters from this plist, to be more precise the database URL, so that I don't have to hardcode it anywhere (other than in that plist).

Of course I could use a dictionary to separately read the plist and retrieve the database url, but I would have expected to access the FIRApp object and retrieve it from there...

Did I miss something or is that option not given to retrieve the Firebase Parameters / Options directly from the FIRApp Object?

Comment: your database url can be retrieved by `FIRDatabase.database().reference()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `FIRDatabase.database().reference()` to get a reference to your database that was loaded via `FIRApp.configure()`.

Comment: Of course if I search in the FIRApp Object I won't find anything... Hmm I kinda knew it must be easy, thanks @tommybananas

Answer (score 0):

I use a very simple extension (**Swift 4**):

```
extension Database {
    var url: URL? {
        let refAsString = "\(FirebaseDatabase.Database.database().reference())"
        return URL(string: refAsString)
    }
}
```